# Changing the border of a tab (windowbuilder)

Tags: eclipse, tabs, border, windowbuilder

I am using Windowbuilder-Pro, and I want to change the Tab borders, in my Windowbuilder desig, they are looking how I want them, but when I test them, they change to another form. (I want them to be Rectangular)

I already tried several things using the UIManager but I can't seem to find a good solution.

How I want them (And how they are in my Windowbuilder design):

[image]

How they are(This is what they look like when I run my application):

[image]